# Graphs and symmetries

Tags: graph-theory

Let us define a symmetric cut of the graph as a cut which cuts the graph into two isomorphic graphs and that the cut preserves the isomorphism i.e. the edges that are cut only connect vertices that are images of each other under this isomorphism. I have a graph that has a property that given any two vertices there exists a symmetric cut that separates them. I would think this is a very restrictive property. One can assume that the graph is regular for simplicity. I know of a family of examples, d-dimensional cubes (their edge and vertex set, as a graph). Can we characterize the general solution to this condition?

Comment: Some easy additions to your family are: even cycles, even-size complete graphs, Cartesian / tensor / strong products of members of the family (this includes the hypercubes). I don't know of a general characterization though.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen I do not think complete graphs are such. The author says `'*this* isomorphism', perhaps meaning that the isomorphism is fixed, not that you consider the family of all isomorphisms between the parts...

Comment: Obviously, the graph is not only regular but vertex-transitive (if connected)

Comment: For the reason Ilya stated, I don't think the class is closed under strong or tensor product.  However, it seems to be closed under cartesian product. So we have the cartesian product of any number of single edges and even length cycles, not necessarily of the same length. I'm wondering if there can be any others.

Comment: Right, I think I was reading something wrong about the cut edges :) But yes, single edges, even cycles and cartesian products.

Comment: Also the graph cannot contain any odd cycles.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I agree with this discussion. I wonder if the graph that is dual to Weyl chamber decomposition (replace every Weyl chamber by a vertex and draw an edge if there is a reflecting plane separating the chambers) will also have this property. I don't quite know what this graph is called.